# Explain function's parameter holding a parameter

Tags: javascript, callback

I'm studying callback concepts and often I see one of the f parameters being used as a "function call" : callback(arr[i]) but it's not a function yet. I imagine we anticipate one of the parameters to be a function so this is an acceptable approach?

Ref:

```
function processArray(arr, callback) {
    var resultArr = new Array();
    for (var i = arr.length - 1; i >= 0; i--)
        resultArr[i] = callback(arr[i]);
    return resultArr;
}
```

Comment: That's what a **callback** is. It's a parameter that's required to hold a function, so that you can call it.

Comment: What do you mean by "it's not a function yet"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look. If you want to process each item of the array and get new array which contains the `length` of string representations, you can do

```js
function processArray(arr, callback) {

    if(typeof callback !== 'function') {
        throw new Error('The callback is not a function');
    }

    const resultArr = new Array();
    
    for (var i = arr.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        resultArr[i] = callback(arr[i]);
    }
    
    return resultArr;
}

const weekdays = ['Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday'];
console.log(processArray(weekdays, item => item.length));
```

What if you want now to uppercase all of them and get another array ?

```js
function processArray(arr, callback) {

    if(typeof callback !== 'function') {
        throw new Error('The callback is not a function');
    }

    const resultArr = new Array();
    
    for (var i = arr.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        resultArr[i] = callback(arr[i]);
    }
    
    return resultArr; 
}

const weekdays = ['Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday'];
console.log(processArray(weekdays, item => item.toUpperCase()));
```

For this two actions if we don't pass an callback function, we need to create 2 separate functions with their own action. With passing parameter we make the function **generic**, so we give the single function the *logic what to do with each item and return the result*.

It will call for each item the function, pass the item into the function as argument and return the result. Then we put the result into the new mapped array.

What about **this is an acceptable approach ?**

Yes this is an acceptable approach. This is a very modern approach. You have one function, which does with each item any logic which you will pass to it. In Javascript there are many many build in functions that use this style (for example [**Array#map**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map), [**Array#forEach**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)). Also a lot of libraries have such type functions.And this is not only in Javacript.

Answer (score 1):

You can make sure to call the callback function, by checking it's a function first, like so :

```
function processArray(arr, callback) {
    var resultArr = new Array();
    for (var i = arr.length - 1; i >= 0; i--)
        resultArr[i] = typeof callback === "function" && callback(arr[i]);
    return resultArr;
}
```

If `callback` is not a function, `resultArr[i]` would be set to `false`.

And if you'd like to set `resultArr[i]` to `null` (or some other value), something like this would work too :

```
resultArr[i] = typeof callback === "function" ? callback(arr[i]) : null
```

Answer (score 1):

`callback` is a variable which holds a function, which you pass as an argument. Of course it's nice to validate the parameter for `function` type.

```
function processArray(arr, callback) {
    var resultArr = new Array();
    for (var i = arr.length - 1; i >= 0; i--)
        resultArr[i] = callback(arr[i]);
    return resultArr;
}

var callback = function () { /* do something */ }
processArray([1, 2, 3], callback) // callback will hold a function you've assigned
```